# MacBook Pro (5,3) Keyboard Weirdness

Tags: 11.04, keyboard, apple

My MacBook Pro (5,3) works almost completely OOTB (with restricted video and WiFi drivers), but I am experiencing some keyboard weirdness.

Specifically to get either (` and ~) or (´ and ¨) I have to press the key twice. Only these two keys behave this way - every other key mapping works.

Keyboard settings are:

- Model: Apple Laptop (due to
  [#538474](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-keyboard/+bug/538474))
- Layout: United Kingdom Macintosh (International)

Comment: I´ve since discovered that the reason those keys require double presses is that they can be used to add accents to other characters (e.g. áèú).

Answer (score 1):

Solved by the OP:

> I´ve since discovered that the reason those keys require double
>   presses is that they can be used to add accents to other characters
>   (e.g. áèú).

Answer (score 0):

xev will give you the key code and its function.

http://crunchbanglinux.org/wiki/xev-determine_custom_keybindings

xmodmap can be used to remap them.

http://www.ehow.com/how_2180748_command-linux-swap-keyboard-keys.html